# Senna.js Support for Two Way Data Binding in Liferay 7.0?

Tags: data-binding, liferay, liferay-7, senna.js

After looking around at Senna.js documentation I couldn't find any indication as to whether the framework has support for two-way data binding, in the context of Liferay 7.0, like Angular2 and React.

Has anyone looked into this? It'll be great if you could share your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay employee here!

Senna.js exists to solve one particular problem: navigation for Single Page Applications. That means it doesn't do two-way data binding.

If you're looking for something like Angular or React, I'd recommend checking [Metal.js](http://metaljs.com/) which is also a Liferay project.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation in regards to two way data binding in Liferay 7.0 using Metal or anything else? Thanks